# Azure Vnet peering with private endpoints

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb, vnet

I have a two vnets (vnet1 and vnet2) I established a peering between them.
I have Web App service with outbound traffic vnet integration set to vnet1.

I have a CosmosDb private endpoint in vnet2.
I use account endpoint and key to authenticate to the Cosmos from the web app.
When I try to access it I'm getting error:

> Response status code does not indicate success: Forbidden (403); Reason: (Request originated from IP xx.xx.xx.xx through public internet. This is blocked by your Cosmos DB account firewall settings.

Could you advice why the traffic goes via public network and how to fix it, please?

Comment: you have to configure the private dns zone.

Comment: @Thomas, yes. Creating private endpoint had created the dns zone.

Comment: are you using the same DNS zone for both vnet ? you need to link both vnet to the dns zone

Comment: @Thomas, yes I just done it, the missing part was linking vnet to dns zone. Thanks. Feel free to add this as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Good to hear that you solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a single private DNS zone for the private endpoint and the DNS Zone must be linked to both VNETs.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to access Cosmos DB private link in vnet2 I got the same error like below:

```
Request originated from IP xx.xx.xx.xx through public internet.his is blocked by your Cosmos DB account firewall settings.
```

[image]

**To resolve this issue**, make use of below steps:

> As long as a valid authorization token is provided, your Azure Cosmos DB account is by default accessible from the internet. For IP policy-based access control to be configured, the user needs to provide a list of IP addresses in CIDR that will be added to the list of client IPs that are permitted to access a certain Azure Cosmos DB account.

Once this configuration is in place, any requests coming from machines that aren't on the permitted list will result in a 403 (Forbidden) response. It is recommended to allow Azure portal to access your account when using IP firewall.

*In your Cosmos -> Networking ->selected network -> add you existing virtual network (vnet2) like below:*

- Make sure to update your firewall settings to add your current IP address to the firewall rules.
- Select the **Allow access from Azure portal** option and save like below:

[image]

Added private endpoint in vnet2:

[image]

Now, when I tried to access my cosmos db account got result successfully like below:

[image]

***Reference***:

[Configure an IP firewall for your Azure Cosmos DB account | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-firewall)

Comment: Hi @Imran your recommendation is against what the private endpoints are for. I'd like to disabled all public network access, so 'Selected networks' are not an option. I want web app to connect with cosmos via private IP address, not through public internet. So the question here is why the web app uses public network rather than private IP.

Comment: Please check this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-private-endpoints)